# xpath on etree element yielding unexpected result

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am running xpath to filter an XML feed with "item" tags. From the list of results, I take the first result and use xpath to filter "title" tag. However, when I filter "title", I am getting a title from xml that did not have an "item" tag. Since I am doing xpath on an "item" result set, the behavior is unexpected. Can anyone tell me what's going on here.

See below code using xpath.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2018-02.xml'
data = urlopen(url)
xml = data.read()
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, huge_tree=True)
root = etree.XML(xml, parser=parser)
items = root.xpath("//item")
first_item = items[0]
title = first_item.xpath("//title")[0].text
print(title)
#'All XBRL Data Submitted to the SEC for 2018-02'
```

I expected first item to be the following:

```
<item>
<title>DST SYSTEMS INC (0000714603) (Filer)</title>
<link>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/714603/000071460318000013/0000714603-18-000013-index.htm</link>
<guid>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/714603/000071460318000013/0000714603-18-000013-xbrl.zip</guid>
<enclosure url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/714603/000071460318000013/0000714603-18-000013-xbrl.zip" length="470442" type="application/zip" />
<description>10-K</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 28 Feb 2018 17:29:39 EST</pubDate>
<edgar:xbrlFiling xmlns:edgar="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar"></item>
```

Instead, when I do:
title = first_item.xpath("//title").text, I get title as ''All XBRL Data Submitted to the SEC for 2018-02'

The title is coming from:

```
<channel>
<title>All XBRL Data Submitted to the SEC for 2018-02</title>
<link>http://www.sec.gov/spotlight/xbrl/filings-and-feeds.shtml</link>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2018-02.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<description>This is a list all of the filings containing XBRL for 2018-02</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<pubDate>Wed, 28 Feb 2018 00:00:00 EST</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 28 Feb 2018 00:00:00 EST</lastBuildDate>
```

But I had run the xpath on items, which did xpath("items"). I am not sure why I am not getting the expected result of 'DST SYSTEMS INC (0000714603) (Filer)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
title = first_item.xpath("//title")[0].text
```

Use:

```
title = first_item.xpath("title")[0].text
```

The difference is "//" before "title".

The reason is that "//title" selects all title elements, **no matter where they are in the document**. Just using "title" will select node with the name "title".